# PHP ob_flush(); it's not flushing

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a script that will create 10 files base on 10 templates (one template per file).

This is my code:

```
$lines = file("files/templist.txt");
$template = "files/templates/template.txt";
$template2 = "files/templates/template2.txt";
$template3 = "files/templates/template3.txt";
$template4 = "files/templates/template4.txt";
$template5 = "files/templates/template5.txt";
$template6 = "files/templates/template6.txt";
$template7 = "files/templates/template7.txt";
$template8 = "files/templates/template8.txt";
$template9 = "files/templates/template9.txt";
$template10 = "files/templates/template10.txt";

ob_start();
include_once($template);
$file_output = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[0].'', $file_output);
ob_flush()

if (empty($lines[1])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template2);
$file_output2 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[1].'', $file_output2);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[2])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template3);
$file_output3 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[2].'', $file_output3);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[3])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template4);
$file_output4 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[3].'', $file_output4);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[4])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template5);
$file_output5 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[4].'', $file_output5);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[5])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template6);
$file_output6 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[5].'', $file_output6);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[6])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template7);
$file_output7 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[6].'', $file_output7);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[7])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template8);
$file_output8 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[7].'', $file_output8);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[8])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template9);
$file_output9 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[8].'', $file_output9);
ob_flush()
}

if (empty($lines[9])) {
} else {
ob_start();
include_once($template10);
$file_output10 = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('files/'.$lines[9].'', $file_output10);
ob_flush()
}
```

files/templist.txt contains 10 lines:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data5
data6
data7
data8
data9
data10
```

My goal is to create 10 files based on templates e.g. data1.txt, data2.txt, data3.txt (...) and data10.txt

Above script creaters only 1 file named data10.txt omitting data1.txt, data2.txt etc etc.
What I'm doing wrong? Cheers! :)

Comment: Ever heard of arrays and loops …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this (Simple)?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    ob_start();
    include('files/templates/template' . $i . '.txt');
    file_put_contents('files/data' . $i, ob_get_clean());
}
```

or this (With `templist.txt` and first template has no number)?

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents("files/templist.txt"));

for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    if (!empty($lines[$i])) {
        ob_start();
        $templatePath = 'files/templates/template.txt';
        if ($i > 1) {
            $templatePath .= $i;
        }
        $templatePath .= '.txt';

        include($templatePath);

        file_put_contents('files/' . $lines[$i], ob_get_clean());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that this code is a total mess and that its syntax is incorrect because of the lack of semicolon at the end of *ob_flush()* call, the main problem is that the filenames you read from the templist.txt file contain a new line - "\n" at the end, except for the data10.txt which is the last line of that file. In such case the creation of the file can fail or your file manager may not be able to display it.

The quickest fix would be to replace the first line with this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents("files/templist.txt"));
```